# how to change the java path that is being referenced

Tags: java, terminal, path

I had had previously installed java on my mac. I just downloaded a new version of java from their website. when i run `java -version` in my terminal I get this

```
omars-mbp:local omarjandali$ java -version
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
omars-mbp:local omarjandali$
```

I want delete the version above and have to point it to the new java version that I just downloaded which is

```
version 8: (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
```

how can i redirect it accordingly

Comment: And how did you install that other version of java? You know, such details do matter. Beyond that, I suggest you try your luck with a search engine, "java macos uninstall" will give you plenty of material to study first. You are not the first person with such problems, and there are detailed explanations out there how to go about it.

Comment: I deleted that 12.0.1 version. I installed java through the installer but when i run java -version it says i dont have java install. how can i add it to the path so i can run java -version @GhostCat

Comment: There are  zillions of ways of installing Java, and many to deinstall. Again: this is a "solved" problem. Go out, and do some research. "I deleted that version". How exactly? So, as said: A) check out the wisdom of the internet, and do proper prior research B) if you are really stuck, then put up a *real* [mcve] that tells people what exactly you did. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you. You are like a person calling his garage "my car making strange noises, now tell me how to fix that".

Comment: ususally use "JAVA_HOME" is a better idea. So if you installed a new one. Just  need change this environment variable.